# Sending data to the frontend from Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am formatting some data to be more readable.

I am sending this data to the frontend, look

code

```
res.status(200).json({dealersData});
```

`dealersData` is a json containing

```
{
  "Dealers":{
    "Detail":[
      {
        "Table":[
          {
            "DealerId":[
              "1"
            ],
            "DealerName":[
              "Carmen"
            ],
            "NickName":[
              "Carmen"
            ],
            "Picture":[
              "00001.jpg"
            ],
            "Active":[
              "1"
            ],
            "LegalId":[
              "111111111"
            ],
            "TypeId":[
              "1"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

so what I need to do with `Lodash` is send the data to the frontend without the '"Dealers":{...}`and without the '"Detail":[...]' part, I need to send it starting the JSON from`"Table"`

lets say like this

```
      {
        "Table":[
          {
            "DealerId":[
              "1"
            ],
            "DealerName":[
              "Carmen"
            ],
            "NickName":[
              "Carmen"
            ],
            "Picture":[
              "00001.jpg"
            ],
            "Active":[
              "1"
            ],
            "LegalId":[
              "111111111"
            ],
            "TypeId":[
              "1"
            ]
          }
```

I already tried but I am getting something like

```
dealersData {[[null]]}
```

so, what are your suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your response to:

```
res.status(200).json(dealersData.Dealers.Detail[0]);
```

Perhaps check data validity:

```
if(dealersData && dealersData.Dealers && dealersData.Dealers.Detail) {
    res.status(200).json(dealersData.Dealers.Detail[0]);
} else {
    res.status(404).json({'success':false});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res.status(200).json(dealersData.Dealers.Detail[0]);
```

Access Dealers key, then first object in Detail array